# How can I insert an image in Keynote 09 that retains a link to an external file?

Tags: keynote

Or even better, how can I embed another .key file inside a keynote presentation. There was support to a "linkback" PDF functionallity similar to what Omnigraffle offers but it doesn't seem to be supported in the latest version

Comment: Do you want to add a keynote into a keynote? Or just other files?

Answer (score 1):

When you add an image to Keynote it copies it into its package.  What I've done is open the package and replace the copy of the image with a link back to the external image.   What I am suggesting isn't simple but does work.